# How to convert an uploaded image to a "dot-to-dot" puzzle?

Tags: plotting, graphics, image, image-processing

I would like to upload an image to *Mathematica* and have the software place numbered points throughout the image so that it appears as a "dot-to-dot" image puzzle. I would also like to specify exactly how many dots I would like to have included. Any ideas how to do this?

I am trying to create an images similar to this idea - http://thomasmakesstuff.com/wp-content/uploads/1985/03/1000-dot-to-dot-book-behance-12.jpg

Comment: Drawing by numbers... sounds like an interesting task,  but also a tall order. You should add more information, sample data and preferably some code to show what you tried already.